# How to create partition on date column for every 1 day in db2

Tags: date, db2, partition

I am trying to create partition on date column but it is not working

Create table test(
All columns)
Partition by range( datecolumn)
( Starting minvalue to maxvalue)

Tried using above script but not working showing token part partition was expected

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You get the following error:

```
Create table test3 (id int, datecolumn date) 
Partition by range (datecolumn) 
(Starting (MINVALUE) Ending (MAXVALUE) every 1 day)

[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0636N  Range specified for data partition "PARTNAME=MINVALUE" is not valid.  Reason code = "11".  SQLSTATE=56016 SQLCODE=-636
```

The explanation:

```
db2 "? SQL0636N"


SQL0636N  Range specified for data partition "<partition-name>" is not
      valid. Reason code = "<reason-code>".

Explanation:

The range specified for the partitioning key is not valid for one of the
following reason codes:
...
11

         MINVALUE and MAXVALUE cannot be specified when the EVERY clause
         is specified.
```

You can't use M*VALUE with EVERY clause.
You would get impractically huge number of partitions, if you had such an ability.
This is not what range partitioning is designed for.

Use one of:

```
Create table test1 (id int, datecolumn date) 
Partition by range (datecolumn) 
(Starting ('2023-01-01') Ending ('2023-01-31') every 1 day)
```

or MDC (which should be suitable for a large number of "partitions" for unknown range values) instead of RANGE:

```
Create table test2 (id int, datecolumn date) 
organize by row using (datecolumn)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W0J9p1Z3)

Comment: When I run your partition by range(datecolumn) ( starting '2023-01-01' ending '2023-01-31' every 1 day) . I am getting sqlcode -199 sqlstate 42601 sqlerrmc starting;part partition

Comment: And when I am using organize by row using datecolumn. I am getting sqlerrmc row;hash

Comment: What's your Db2 platform and version?

Comment: Db2 Version 11.1

Comment: I've sent you a link with exactly the same version as yours - Db2 for Linux, Unix and Windows v11.1. And it works there. Either you don't really use Db2 for LUW or you are doing something wrong...